# Changing color of text in TextView which is rendered using ArrayAdapter in android activity

Tags: android

I am using the following xml tag inside selector tag :

```
        <item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/red"/>
        <item android:color="@color/black"/>
```

This selector i use to specify the textColor of a TextView (file named = country_code_spinner_item).

This TextView is used inside the following ArrayAdapter :

```
        ArrayList<String> countrySpinnerOptions = new ArrayList<>(
                        CountryData.getInstance().getSortedCountryCodes());
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                        R.layout.country_code_spinner_item,
                        countrySpinnerOptions)

This adapter is added to a **Spinner Object**.

Inside the file named = **country_code_spinner_item**
    I have specified :   **android:enabled="false"**
    and     **android:textColor="@color/country_code_selector"**

Here country_code_selector is the file in which i have specified :
        **<item android:state_enabled="true" android:color="@color/red"/>**
```

Now when this TextView will be rendered the enabled tag is set to false as hardcoded.
The TextView's textColor should be set to black. But i see the textColor as red eventhough i have specified the android:enabled = false which should then select the 2nd option in selector.

I basically want to keep the color of text in TextView by default to black and when the TextView is Tapped (This is a spinner object) I want the color to be changed permanently to red.
It does not seem to be direct to me as how to do it using

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an ArrayAdapter all items are enabled be default (unless the adapter return false from `isEnabled` method), because `areAllItemsEnabled` method returns true in `BaseAdapter`.

You could try using the `android:state_checked` state instead or creating a custom adapter that set enabled true/false on the TextView based on the current selected position.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try this:

spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:text="Text View"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerText"
    android:layout_height="60dp">

</TextView>
```

In your activity where you populate your spinner try

```
your_spinner_object.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.spinnerText);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

hope it helps!!!